# Converting instance of Interface with generic method to Action

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates, action

I'm struggling to create instances of `Action<>` using the `MethodInfo`'s I can retrieve using reflection.

Using the example below I can easily call a custom method on my objects, but I would really like to convert them to Actions.

I have tried doing it by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` but I can't seem to get this to return an Action with a generic type.

**Example**

I have created the following interface:

```
interface IMyTest { } // Marker interface
interface<TInput> IMyTest : IMyTest {
    void MyMethod(TInput input);
}
```

Then I inherit the interface in a class:

```
class MyClass : IMyTest<DateTime>, IMyTest<int> {
    void MyMethod(DateTime input) {
        // Do something
    }
    void MyMethod(int input) {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

And then I create a method that uses reflection to find and call "MyMethod" from the interface instance:

```
void DoCallMyMethod(object target, object input) {
    IEnumerable<Type> interfaces = target.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        .Where(x => typeof(IMyTest).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsGenericType);

    foreach (Type @interface in interfaces) {
        Type type = @interface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        MethodInfo method = @interface.GetMethod("MyMethod", new Type[] { type });

        if (method != null) {
            method.Invoke(target, new[] { input });
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I put it all together:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
DoCallMyMethod(foo, DateTime.Now);
DoCallMyMethod(foo, 47);
```

**What I would want**

Inside `DoCallMyMethod` I would like `MethodInfo method` to be converted to a generic `Action` so that the result would be something like this:

```
Action<type> myAction = method;
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

I found some similar SO posts (but none that cover exactly my case) that ended up with an answer similar to this:

```
Action<object> action = 
    (Action<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object>), target, method);
```

But this doesn't work because "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

How can I get an Action with the specified `type` as its input type, while still retaining the object references (without new instances appearing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an `Action<object>` from one of `MyMethod`s because the method is expecting a specific object's type (`int`, `DateTime`) and if you treat it as an `Action<object>` you might invoke it with objects of any type.

Since what you need is return a `Action<T>` there is not need to pass the input value to `DoCallMyMethod` method. You can pass the input type as a generic parameter:

```
public Action<T> DoCallMyMethod<T>(object target)
{
    var @interface = typeof(IMyTest<T>);
    if (@interface.IsAssignableFrom(target.GetType()))
    {
        var method = @interface.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        if (method != null)
        {
            var action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), target, method) as Action<T>;                    
            return action;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
var action1 = DoCallMyMethod<DateTime>(foo);
var action2 = DoCallMyMethod<int>(foo);

action1(DateTime.Now);
action2(47);
```

If you don't know at compile time the type of the input you can try this:

```
public Delegate DoCallMyMethod(object target, Type inputType)
{
    var @interface = typeof(IMyTest<>).MakeGenericType(inputType);
    if (@interface.IsAssignableFrom(target.GetType()))
    {
        var method = @interface.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        if (method != null)
        {
            var @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(inputType), target, method);
            return @delegate;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
var action1 = DoCallMyMethod(foo, typeof(DateTime)) as Action<DateTime>;
var action2 = DoCallMyMethod(foo, typeof(int)) as Action<int>;

action1(DateTime.Now);
action2(47);

//or

int input = 47;
var @delegate = DoCallMyMethod(foo, input.GetType());
@delegate.DynamicInvoke(input);
```

But if you need to returns an `Action<object>` you can make an action receiving an object and calling the method if the object's type is valid:

```
public Action<object> DoCallMyMethod(object target, Type inputType)
{
    var @interface = typeof(IMyTest<>).MakeGenericType(inputType);
    if (@interface.IsAssignableFrom(target.GetType()))
    {
        var method = @interface.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        if (method != null)
        {
            Action<object> action = obj =>
            {
                if (obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(inputType))
                    method.Invoke(target, new object[] { obj });
            };

            return action;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And...

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
Action<object> action = DoCallMyMethod(foo, typeof(int));
action(47);         // MyMethod(int) is called.
action("...");      // Nothing happens.
```

Now you have an `Action<object>` that calls `MyMethod(int)` only when an integer is passed.

Comment: It somehow works, but there's one more step that I need that I can't infer from your answer (and which might have been unclear from the question). Once I have the `delegate` without knowing the type of the input, how can I get a generic Action<> from it? If I, for instance, also have a method `AddExternalCaller<T>(Action<T> callback)`, the `callback` could here be one of the variants of `MyMethod`. How can I then get both `AddExternalCaller()` and `DoCallMyMethod()` to add an action to a global collection of `List<Action<object>>`?

Comment: @GTHvidsten: But you can't add an `Action<T>` like `Action<int>` or `Action<DateTime>` to a `List<Action<object>>` because an `Action<int>` isn't an `Action<object>`. You can't invoke a method passing an object when it is expecting a `int`. In fact, this is valid in the other direction since `Action<T>` is contravariant, you can assign an `Action<object>` to an `Action<int>` variable, you can invoke a method that is expecting an object with an integer. I think you need to change the design how you save the callbacks.

Comment: One way I've converted from `Action<T>` to `Action<object>` before is to convert it using this syntax: `void Convert<T>(Action<T> callback) { Action<object> foo = input => callback((T)input); }`. I was able to convert the dynamic delegate to Action<object> like this: `Action<object> handler = request => @delegate.DynamicInvoke(request);`. As of right now it work in my scenario as well. Do you see any particular drawbacks with this?

Comment: @GTHvidsten Well if call any of these delegates with the wrong type an exception would be trown. If you store an `Action<int>` an invoke it with an `string` object.

Comment: I'll add some additional backend to make sure I only retrieve the `Action<>` instances with the correct types, so I should be covered... I hope :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Another option could be change your `List<Action<object>>` to something like `Dictionary<Type, List<Action<object>>>` or `Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>>` to group actions according the input type.

Comment: That was my plan all along ;)